# Concurrent Read and Write 2 Map Inside Loop Range

Tags: for-loop, go, goroutine

I'm trying to read and write two separate maps inside one loop range. The problem is the output is not consistent between call. I trying to create REST API using go chi.

```
var mapMutex = sync.RWMutex{}

// Root map
var rootLocationMap = make(map[int]*LocationViewDto)

// Child map
var childLocationMap = make(map[int]*LocationViewDto)

// Insert map here

for _, location := range childLocationMap {
        mapMutex.RLock()
        temp, isExist := rootLocationMap[*location.ParentId]
        mapMutex.RUnlock()

        if isExist {
            temp.Children = append(temp.Children, *location)

            mapMutex.Lock()
            rootLocationMap[*location.ParentId] = temp
            mapMutex.Unlock()

        } else {
            mapMutex.RLock()
            temp, isExist = childLocationMap[*location.ParentId]
            mapMutex.RUnlock()

            temp.Children = append(temp.Children, *location)

            mapMutex.Lock()
            childLocationMap[*location.ParentId] = temp
            mapMutex.Unlock()
        }
    }
```

Comment: You ranging over `childLocationMap` and also trying to modify `childLocationMap` using key  `*location.ParentId`. I think you're aware of that? Perhaps that's why the output is inconsistent. Do elaborate more on what you're trying to achieve!

Comment: I'm trying to show tree in a JSON structure. This particular loop is used for populate the Children of all map that have same ID as the ParentID. The inconsistency occur when I call the API, sometimes it returns the correct JSON and sometimes it returns incomplete JSON.

Comment: You're only protecting reading and writing of the maps, but the values you are modifying are still going to have data races. What does the race detector show? It's hard to determine what this is supposed to do with a contrived example, but there's no synchronization of the control flow logic here; for example, is it valid for all goroutines to be in the `else` block at the same time with the same value?

Comment: So the solution is to not loop over `childLocationMap`?

Comment: We can't say, because you never gave us a problem statement. The basic solution to the data races that may be present in the example above is to only modify the maps and their contents with one goroutine at a time.